# VB.net and Pdf file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have lot of PDF pages which can be opened on click of a button in vb.net. I am using sql 2008 (I am working with the Files for the first time).
I tried by placing the .pdf file inside the solution explorer and as below code, it worked.

```
       <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"
        NavigateUrl="~/Custopo.pdf">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

For each `Order ID`, I have lot of PDF files that can be opened by the user on click of hyperlink or button. Hence, which is the best way to save the PDF links ie in sql database or solution explorer or any other best option?

Comment: why don't you store the PDF files as byte[] array in the DB? Then pull them up when you need them? At least you will have them stored in the database meaning easy to backup rather than files on disk and you will have less of a hit accessing the disk than the database (depending on network conditions etc...). you also have not provided a reason on why you are thinking about saving the links in the SQL DB? Why would you want to save just the links in a DB? That makes no sense.

Comment: Each link is related to each orderid.Hence when a user see the details of order in a repeater they are allowed to open that link.That is why i am planning to save in DB.

Comment: the best thing is to store the PDF's in the database. then when the user clicks, you already have the ID and query the DB based on that ID and pull the PDF back and write it to the Response Stream for download.

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I'd search all pdf files in defined directory and create hyperlink of every file.